# Add column from single dimension list pyspark efficiently

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing ensemble learning and I want to put the ensembled single column matrix into the original Dataframe used to gather the data.

The `df` looks like this, with repeating UserId every six rows.

```
+------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|UserId|TrackId|Predictor1|Predictor2|Predictor3|Predictor4|Predictor5|Predictor6|
+------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|199810| 105760|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|
|199810|  18515|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|
|199810| 242681|         1|         1|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|
|199810|  74139|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|
|199810| 208019|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|
|199810|   9903|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|        -1|
|199812| 142408|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|
+------+-------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

and the `s_ensemble` matrix looks like

```
[[ 0.72892909]
 [ 0.72892909]
 [-0.58959307]
 ...
 [-0.72892909]
 [-0.72892909]
 [-0.72892909]]
```

both have the same amount of rows being 120000.

I'm creating a Dataframe for the matrix flattened into an array and adding an index column to both dataframes, joining the two on the same index and then dropping it.

```
df = df.select('UserId', 'TrackID').withColumn("row_idx", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
b = spark.createDataFrame([np.array(s_ensemble).flatten().tolist(),], ['Ensembled_Prediction']).withColumn("row_idx", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))

df = df.join(b, df.row_idx == b.row_idx).drop("row_idx")
```

This works to create it, but I am unable to see what it looks like and I believe I'm maxing out my machine's memory as it spikes after merging these two Dataframes together. I see this as an exception trying to `df.show(5)`.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1086.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9 in stage 159.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9.0 in stage 159.0 (TID 166) (host.docker.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
```

I bumped my jupyter notebook to use 16gs and I also maxed out RAM on the free version of colab.

Is there another way to add a single dimension matrix to an existing Dataframe without creating multiple temporary large Dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Apache Spark handles your solution to create a dataframe index not very well. If both dataframes have the same number of partitions (be sure to specify explicitly), you can just use:

withColumn("row_idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

It is more sane though to create the index in the input data before feeding it into pyspark, e.g. using np.ndenumerate(s_ensemble).